# How to say a movie is not for the general public?

Tags: idioms, vocabulary, translation, idiom-request

In Czech we say it's "*viewer-demanding*" (divácky náročný). This can either mean it's "a movie that requires deep comprehension on the part of hte viewer" or that it's "a movie that requires being an artist or a movie critic".

How could I say something like:

> *The OA* is not a series for the late Sunday night. It requires you to concentrate and to be sensitive to every little allusion in the way people speak.

Is there a similar idiom in English?

Comment: Would that be **restrictive**? See the ["Comparison table" here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_picture_content_rating_system).

Comment: Do you mean "a movie that requires deep comprehension on the part of hte viewer", "a movie not for the ordinary mind"?

Comment: Could you explain how it is not for the general audience in your usage? It could be viewer age restrictions or content just not interesting to average people.

Comment: We do use the verb **demands** and the adjective **demanding** of works of art that require the audience to be fully engaged with their ideas and/or to surrender their own opinions while watching or reading. (The film demands ....  This demanding film....)  Sometimes these words can be "code" for "the average person won't get it and won't enjoy it".

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Yes, thank you, this is exactly what I meant. It's not really clear what we mean - sometimes we want to express it's intelectually difficult so it's not for a lazy friday evening, othertimes we mean it's too philosophical to be understood by someone who isn't an artist/movie critic.

Comment: @user3169 It's not interesting to average people.

Comment: @CowperKettle I find those 2 options very similar and we use "demanding" (náročný) for both of them but I'd rather see the latter translated.

Comment: Note that we do not refer to television series as *movies*. You have referred to *the OA* in your question. This is not a movie. It's a television series or television show.

Comment: Maybe not the answer you are looking for, but the term "film connoisseur" may be useful here. It is not an idiom of English, but will be understood. You might say "This movie is for film connoisseurs".

Answer (score 4):

Is this film not for the general public because it's offensive to some people or because it's intellectually demanding so that many people won't enjoy it?

In the first case we might in the US say the film is "X-rated" (if it has extremely graphic sexual content) or "R-rated" (if it is not suitable for children due to suggestive sexual content or violence) or "for mature audiences".

In the second case, we might call the film an "[art film](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Art_film)".

Answer (score 0):

To add on to Photon's answer:

> An **intellectual** film
>
> A **thought-provoking** film
>
> An **art / art-house / artsy** film
>
> A **specialty** film.

In some cases these might be also called "experimental" films or "independent" films.

Comment: Thank you, isn't there a phrase when you want to actually express it's **too** specialty?

Comment: @Probably  There are several, but I would say it's a "niche" or "niche market" film.